# Recursive CTE Error: Types do not match

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression, type-mismatch

I have this CTE

```
WITH items AS ( 
        SELECT 1 AS lvl, 
               i.[No_] [Parent Item No_], 
               i.[No_], 
               i.[Description], 
               CAST(N'' AS NVARCHAR(20)) /* COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CS_AS  */ 
        FROM Item i
        LEFT JOIN KitComponent bc ON bc.[Parent Item No_] = i.[No_] 
        LEFT JOIN Item ci ON ci.[No_] = bc.[No_] 
        GROUP BY i.[No_], i.[Description], i.[Unit Price] 

        UNION ALL

        SELECT i.lvl + 1, 
               i.[No_], 
               i2.[No_], 
               i2.[Description], 
               CAST(bc.[Variant Code] AS NVARCHAR(20)) 
        FROM KitComponent bc
        JOIN items i ON i.[No_] = bc.[Parent Item No_]
        JOIN Item i2 ON i2.[No_] = bc.[No_] 
) 
SELECT * FROM items WHERE [Parent Item No_] = '4000540001'
```

It works on one server, without that commented part specifying the collation.  Then I copy the whole thing into another window where a replicated copy of the same database lives on another server and get this error.

> *Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "Variant Code" of recursive query "items".*

I originally didn't have those `CAST` functions either, it worked just fine on server #1.  Finally I put the collate command in the top part of the CTE and then it works on both machines.

I check the version by `SELECT @@VERSION`

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP3) (KB3072779) - 11.0.6020.0 (X64) 
  Oct 20 2015 15:36:27 
  Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)
  (Hypervisor)

Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP3) (KB3072779) - 11.0.6020.0 (X64) 
  Oct 20 2015 15:36:27 
  Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)
  (Hypervisor)
```

and they are identical, so I think this must be some option setting that's different.

Does anybody know where I look to see what option that is?

Comment: Quick guess: database collation <> table(column) collation. Right click on DB - properties ->  collation, then do the same on tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [WITH](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) doc:

> **The data type of a column in the recursive member must be the same as the data type of the corresponding column in the anchor member.**

So it should have the same datatype,length,collation, ....

In your example:

```
WITH items AS ( 
        SELECT 1 AS lvl, 
               i.[No_] [Parent Item No_], 
               i.[No_], 
               i.[Description], 
               CAST(N'' AS NVARCHAR(20)) -- default DB collation
        FROM Item i
        LEFT JOIN KitComponent bc ON bc.[Parent Item No_] = i.[No_] 
        LEFT JOIN Item ci ON ci.[No_] = bc.[No_] 
        GROUP BY i.[No_], i.[Description], i.[Unit Price] 

        UNION ALL

        SELECT i.lvl + 1, 
               i.[No_], 
               i2.[No_], 
               i2.[Description], 
               CAST(bc.[Variant Code] AS NVARCHAR(20)) -- column collation
        FROM KitComponent bc
        JOIN items i ON i.[No_] = bc.[Parent Item No_]
        JOIN Item i2 ON i2.[No_] = bc.[No_] 
) 
SELECT * FROM items WHERE [Parent Item No_] = '4000540001';
```

Check

```
SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX(DB_NAME(), 'Collation')
```

and:

```
SELECT COLLATION_NAME,*
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS      
WHERE table_name = 'KitComponent'
  AND column_name = 'Variant Code'
```

Comment: I ran your two queries, for the db collation name and the collation name of the column, and the server where it all works came up like this

DB collation name -> Latin1_General_100_CS_AS
column collation name -> Latin1_General_100_CS_AS

And the one where I had to cast and then specify collation to get the same code to work comes up like this:

DB collation name -> SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
column collation name -> Latin1_General_100_CS_AS

Comment: I might add that the word “same” isn’t clear enough. What it means is completely, exactly, anally retentively the same.